# MySQL Column Update with trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have this reservation table that has `RESERVATION_ID , ROOM_NUM, Date_Start , Date_End and cost columns`. what I want to do is insert all the columns except cost and fill the cost automatically.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check before INSERT ON reservation
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.RESERVATION_COST = NULL THEN
            SET NEW.RESERVATION_COST = 'timestampdiff(day, NEW.RESERVATION_STARTD, NEW.RESERVATION_ENDD)*70';
        END IF;
    END;//
delimiter ;
```

I wrote this `trigger` to do it, but whenever I press Apply to insert everything nothing is inserted to the `RESERVATION_COST` column.

why?

Comment: Change if condition as `'IF NEW.RESERVATION_COST IS NULL THEN'` and check if it has any effect !!??

Comment: Don't use =null in SQL statements. Use is null.

Comment: Thank you all :D @Tim3880 ' s method worked

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment if I had enough reputation, but anyways. Triggers cannot act on the same table which activated them.  Seems limiting, but we've had the same issue.

This link doesn't explicitly say this but it does say "in the associated table".  Not the same: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: I made it work I just had to change  = Null and remove the ' ' from the SET statement

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a value to `NULL`, you need to check if it `IS NULL` instead.

e.g.

```
 IF NEW.RESERVATION_COST IS NULL THEN
```